# I uninstalled Microsoft Edge Browser, now can't restore it. Windows 10

Tags: browser

I uninstalled the browser using a tool I found on the internet, but now I can't restore it. I have tried the following:

- Reinstall Windows 10.
- Use a powerShell solution (deleting the package on appData folder, then using a command on powershell, not working since I don't have any folders to delete).
- Copy the Microsoft Edge folders `Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy`,`Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe` and `MicrosoftEdge` from another computer
- I tried to copy the exe file of the browser from another computer, but couldn't find it on the path that's writted on it's shortcut: `C:\Users\Elyasaf\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.

How can I restore Edge?

Comment: A Windows reinstall should bring it back...are you doing a full reinstall or just a refresh? Which tool did you use to uninstall Edge initially?

Comment: I know! but unfortunately it doesn't. I fully uninstalled the windows 4 times already. I have used the software (script) provided in this link:https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-uninstall-remove-edge-browser-from-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

I've researched this quite a lot, and here is the solution:

If you uninstalled your Microsoft Edge browser using the script in [this link](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-uninstall-remove-edge-browser-from-windows-10/), or for any reason what-soever you can't reinstall Edge using the [tuturial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oL2oqS_SjE), all you gotta do is to perform an in-place upgrade with Windows 10.

To do that, simply click [this link](http://aka.ms/W10InplaceUpgrade7) and follow the instructions.
keep in mind all your data and apps will be safe, I've done this myself.

*IMPORTANT*: If you are using a laptop, make sure it's plugged-in to power, since it may take sometime and drain your battery, and you don't want your laptop to shutdown in the middle of this process because it has no battery left.

Best of luck!